# AWS Cognito OpenID/OIDC UserPool Identity : "username attribute mapping required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

i'm using Cognito's UserPool to login my users with an OpenID service.

I've mapped the UserPool **username** attribute to the Federated identity's **sub** attribute (which was by default), but when trying to authenticate, after the Cognito OAuth callback I get the error "username attribute mapping required"

I've tried to put other attributes to map the UserPool **username**, but I get the same error or Cognito refuses to map the attribute.

**Here's my OIDC configuration** :

[image: OIDC configuration here]

**OIDC Provider configuration** :

[image]

The OpenID specs : https://auth.riotgames.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

**On the front-end side, I use :**

```
  const FederatedSignIn = async () => {
    const oauth = {
      domain: myDomain',
      scope: ['profile', 'openid'],
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:8000/login',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:8000/logout',
      responseType: 'code',
      attributes: { // I tried this but it doesn't change anything
        username: 'sub',
      },
    }
    Auth.configure({ oauth })
    Auth.federatedSignIn({ customProvider: 'rso' })
  }
```

Also, whenever I add the **sub** field in scope, I get a **invalid_scope** error..

Any Help is greatly appreciated !

I found similar questions here :

- [AWS Cognito attributes OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324778/aws-cognito-attributes-openid)
- [Cognito - error_description username attribute mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430759/cognito-error-description-username-attribute-mapping)

I'm starting to ask myself if this is a Cognito issue but that would be very surprising..

Comment: Hey, did you manage to resolve it? I am getting the same error and I could use some help, if you know how did you solve.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt to be honest it's been a while. I remember i've had a hard time mapping the OIDC attributes. You need to map the `Username` User pool attribute i think.
Also after checking quickly, in the Allowed Oauth scopes for the App client, i authorized the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope.
If it still doesn't work, i suggest you look at the Frontend oauth attributes, maybe it's coming from there

Comment: It turned out that i was using the FB scopes as the `attribute` names in Mapping. For example, user.location or user.hometown to fetch. ideally it should be attributes that you specify in `fields` of /me Graph API endpoint, attributes that are being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize scopes should be seperated by space , not commas.